# Will memset vector to 0 cause memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks, vector, memset

I have a structure as followed:

```
typedef enum tBrowseType
{
    catNowPlaying,
    catFolder,
    catFile,
    catGenre
};

typedef struct tBrowseList
{
    int total;
    vector<tBrowseType>browseType;
};
```

After the initial use, I did a memset; will this memset cause memory leak?

Comment: Hard to say if you don't show the memset call.

Answer (score 0):

If you've zeroed the `vector<tBrowseType>` object it is more likely to cause segfault. `memset` is not the way to treat decent `c++` object.

Comment: I did a testing; Before memset, I did a push_back, the first address of the vector is, say 0x00, after memset, I did another push_back, but this time, the first address of the vector becomes 0x02.